# Return an NSString from UIViewController without delegate iOS7

Tags: ios

I want to return an `NSString` from a `UIViewController`, called `InputUIViewController`, to the previous `UIViewController`, called `CallerUIViewController`, which presented `InputUIViewController`. Is there a more concise way to do this in iOS7 than using a delegate? Perhaps using blocks?

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void){
          // something in here?
     }];
}
```

Comment: In a word or two: "delegate pattern".

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm asking if there's a way to do this without using a delegate.....

Comment: Probably, but using a delegate is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass data to any controller that you have a reference to, which in this case is self.presentingViewController. It's not the best way, but here is how you can do it,

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
     CallerUIViewController *caller = (CallerUIViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
     caller.someStringProperty = stringIWantToPass; 
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

This causes a tighter coupling between your controllers than using a delegate, because the presented controller has to know the class of the presenting controller, and also know that it was presented, rather than pushed, or gotten to some other way (which means the controller will be less reusable). If you're not concerned with that, then this method is probably the simplest way to accomplish what you want. Delegation is a better, more general way to do this kind of thing, since the controller doesn't have to know anything about the delegate other than it will implement its delegate protocol, which is why Apple recommends the delegate pattern for passing data back to previous controllers.